# BibTeX alphebetizes author by "von" rather than last name

Tags: bibtex, amsmath, alphabet

I have a BibTeX entry with

> author=Julius von Braun

which is sorted under `v` rather than `B`. It doesn't matter whether I write it as above or as

> author=von Braun, Julius

or with various quotings. It also doesn't seem to matter whether I use `@inbook` or `@book`.

I am using

```
\bibliographystyle{plain}
```

I've tested that using styles `abbrv`, `acm`, and `siam` gives the same sort order, while `ieeetr` and `unsrt` leave the references unsorted.

Comment: The handling of the name 'prefix' and its sorting is determined by the bibliography style you use. If you don't like the way your style handles this, you either have to modify it (if you need help with that, you should tell us which style you use and provide a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864)/[MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4407/35864)) or pick a different style that handles names like you intend. A hack like `author = {Braun, Wernher von}` might be possible, but is not a nice solution.

Comment: The sorting is determined by the `bibliographystyle`.  Which one are you using?

Comment: @AndrewSwann `\bibliographystyle{plain}`

Comment: @moewe I'm using `plain`, but I've now tested many styles (edited into the question) all yielding the same result.

Answer (score 1):

You can modify `plain.bst` (find a local copy via `kpsewhich plain.bst`) by locating

```
FUNCTION {sort.format.names}
```

and changing the line in that function

```
      s nameptr "{vv{ } }{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
```

to

```
      s nameptr "{ll{ }}{  ff{ }}{vv{ } }{  jj{ }}" format.name$ 't :=
```

This is the line that builds the sort key, the von part is the `vv`, this change moves it to before the `jj` for the junior part.
Calling this new file `rplain.bst` we get

[image: Sample output]

from

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{rplain}
\bibliography{test}
\end{document}
```

with `test.bib`

```
@Article{And,
  author =   {And, A.},
  title =    {Duck relations},
  journal =  {J. Ducks},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{And:Duck,
  author =   {von And, J.},
  title =    {Duck progress},
  journal =  {J. Ducks},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{Anders,
  author =   {Anders, D.},
  title =    {Duck news},
  journal =  {J. Ducks},
  year =     2000
}

@Article{Duck,
  author =   {Duck, D.},
  title =    {Duck ideas},
  journal =  {J. Ducks},
  year =     2000
}
```

Alternatively you can create your own bibliographystyle via the custom-bib package.  Run

```
latex makebst
```

and answer the questions; one option is to ignore von parts when sorting.